# Magento 2 Authorize.net and Billing Information loaded simultaneously

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, authorize.net

I am having virtual products in my magento store and want to use authorize.net in the checkout process.

However, when I activate the authorize.net checkout it seems that the billing information and the credit card fields are loaded automatically.

[image]

As you can see, I have right below the billing information the "Cancel" and "Update" button. So in order to be able to place the order, I would have to enter the billing information, click UPDATE, then enter the credit card information and then place the order.

This seems a bit weird to me, however i tried it on different magento installations and it always looked the same... Is there any configuration option I might be missing? Or any way I can omit the UPDATE step somehow?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The same happens with the update and order button when there's a $0 total, no credit card field for $0 total, but the update button must be clicked before the order can be placed - I thought it was odd as well. Reproduced using default luma install on magento 2.2.2

Comment: do you have the same problem if there is a checkout amount greater than 0$ ?